# How to specify a request parameter as Json type

Tags: scala, finagle, finch, twitter-finagle

I am creating a Finch endpoint which expects a Json.

URL - LogBundles/Long JSON Message/Process

I am using json4s library for Json parsing

How do I specify the body as type json Or how do I pass a Json value between LogBundles and Process?

I cannot do body.as[case class] because I wont be knowing the exact structure of Json.
I will be just looking out for a specific key while parsing.

**Code**

```
val bundleProcessEndpoint: Endpoint[String] = put("LogBundles" :: body :: "Process" ) { id =>
                 val jsonBody = parse(id)}
```

**ERROR**

could not find implicit value for parameter d: io.finch.Decode.Aux[A,CT]
[error]         val bundleProcessEndpoint: Endpoint[String] = put("LogBundles" :: body :: "Process" ) { id:JsonInput =>

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of doing this, although none of them is considered idiomatic for Finch. The more-or-less safe way to accept an arbitrary JSON object within an `Endpoint` is to drop down to JSON AST API exposed via the JSON library you're using. For json4s it's going to be `org.json4s.JsonAST.JValue`.

```
scala> import io.finch._, io.finch.json4s._, org.json4s._

scala> implicit val formats: Formats = DefaultFormats
formats: org.json4s.Formats = org.json4s.DefaultFormats$@5ee387bc

scala> val e = jsonBody[JsonAST.JValue]
e: io.finch.Endpoint[org.json4s.JsonAST.JValue] = body

scala> e(Input.post("/").withBody[Application.Json](Map("foo" -> 1, "bar" -> "baz"))).awaitValueUnsafe()
res2: Option[org.json4s.JsonAST.JValue] = Some(JObject(List((foo,JInt(1)), (bar,JString(baz)))))
```

This will give you a `JsonAST.JValue` instance that you'd need to manually manipulate with (I assume there is a pattern-matching API exposed for that).

An alternative (and way more dangerous) solution would be to ask Finch/JSON4S to decode a JSON object as `Map[String, Any]`. However, this only works if you don't expect your clients sending JSON arrays as top-level entities.

```
scala> import io.finch._, io.finch.json4s._, org.json4s._

scala> implicit val formats: Formats = DefaultFormats
formats: org.json4s.Formats = org.json4s.DefaultFormats$@5ee387bc

scala> val b = jsonBody[Map[String, Any]]
b: io.finch.Endpoint[Map[String,Any]] = body

scala> b(Input.post("/").withBody[Application.Json](Map("foo" -> 1, "bar" -> "baz"))).awaitValueUnsafe()
res1: Option[Map[String,Any]] = Some(Map(foo -> 1, bar -> baz))
```

Comment: Hello Vladimir, Correct me if I am wrong.  But my question was how to consume the Json payload from the endpoint for a PUT request sent by the user. WithBody Overrides the Payload sent by the user.

Comment: The last lines in those two examples are just to demonstrate what the endpoint returns on a given input. You don't need it in your application. I encourage you to have a look at our [user guide](https://finagle.github.io/finch/user-guide.html) that should help you to clear up all the confusion.